# Is it possible to have a scrollbar that takes no space?

Tags: codenameone

I'd like to have scrollbars with no extension - that is no scrollbar is shown but a transparent scroll thumb which shows and hides automatically.

This may not be possible with Codename One, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You can override `getSideGap` to always return 0 and it should work. This is something we had as a demo way back in the LWUIT days.

Comment: I want this for all scrollable Container instances. It would be nice if Codename One supported custom factories for Containers and the like. That way one could easily extend those.

Comment: I set a Round Border on UIID ScrollThumb with the Rectangle option which reduced it to a circle. I wonder why that is

Comment: When dragging a scrollable Container the fadeScrollBarBool constant is true and the scrollbar was fully faded out before tap to drag the scrollbar is not shown until the pointer is released. I don't like that

Comment: When settting the border of the ScrollThumb UIID to Rounded it is no circle as when setting it to Round Border. There must be something wrong with Round Border

Comment: When the `Container` is scrolled by `Container.scrollRectToVisible` or by `Container.scrollComponentToVisible` while the scrollbar is not faded out the scrollbar doesn't fade out until the Container is manually scrolled again.

Comment: When the `Container` is scrolled by `Container.scrollRectToVisible` or by `Container.scrollComponentToVisible` while the scrollbar is faded out the scrollbar does not show up.

Comment: And there is that strange state where `com.codename1.ui.plaf.LookAndFeel.drawScroll(Graphics, Component, float, float, boolean, int, int, int, int, Component, Component)` calls `com.codename1.ui.Component.getScrollOpacity()` which sets `scrollOpacity = 0xff`if `Display.getInstance().shouldRenderSelection()` whilst `Component.animate` tries to fade it out - and it never fades out unless manually scrolled again.

Comment: I suppose the only reasonably way to handle this is to override `com.codename1.ui.Component.paintScrollbarY(Graphics)` and handle all conditions there as the standard functionality seems to be of no use

Comment: Rectangle in the round border is always horizontal as the use case is for button not scrollbar. I'm not sure if this is something we'd want to fix as it might create odd looking shapes in cases where one would expect a larger circle. 

You can override the look and feel class and draw whatever you want for the scrollbar there. This will work everywhere universally.